# What strategy to use to determine JSON or XML?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When using Spring, what is considered best practice when both JSON and XML is to be returned?

Say I have a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="items/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Item getItem(@PathVariable, Long id) {
   // Find and return item.
}
```

How can I invoke this in a style like:
`localhost:8080/app-name/items/1.xml` and `localhost:8080/app-name/items/1.json` and get the data in their respective formats?

Comment: You should rather use content negotiation method based on `Accept` HTTP header. It's meant to do this.

Comment: I agree with Peter, doing something more RESTful would be considered a better practice than forcing the response format via an extension.

Comment: Thanks, the both of you. One question, though, doesn't the extension in the `URI` make it more **representational** in terms that it shows exactly *what* it *is* you're obtaining? Just curious. :)

Comment: There is a school of thought (see REST) that your URI should just represent a resource, and the format of it should be performed with content-negotiation (via the Accept header).  The reason for this is that you can easily add new formats to the same resource, as well as deprecate formats, without having to change links to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed in the Spring documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations).

1. You can use two separate URLs to determine the type to return
2. You can use accept headers. However from a browser you are unable to set the accept headers. Therefore using separate URL's gives more control.

Answer (score 4):

Most obvious solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value="items/{id}.{format}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Item getItem(@PathVariable, Long id, String format) {
   if(format.equals("xml"))
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use @ResponseBody and ensure that you have HttpMessageConverters registered with your HandlerAdapter that can handle your object Item with the JSON and XML mime types.  This also allows you to keep from duplicating controllers that return the same Item and keeps your code simpler to maintain and test.

See this for additional info:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-restful/